# Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: localhost:10.0

Tags: ssh, display, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am on the new end of learning remote connections and I ran into a rather strange issue when connecting remotely to a machine.

Host: Jetson Nano - Ubuntu
Client: Asus desktop - Linux Mint

I am using SSH to connect to the host machine. Once I'm in, I run my program which should open the camera that the host machine has connected via mipi connection... but it does not show a display window. Rather it displays:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: lcocalhost:10.0
CONSUMER: Done Success 
(Argus)Error InvalidState: Argus client is exiting with 2 outstanding client threads
```

If run the program in the machine without SSH connection, it works and the display shows what the camera is capturing. I tried changing the `X11forwarding` and `agent` to YES, and I tried `export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0`. That did not work as well.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks, GM

Comment: If you haven't check the following link, you might review the suggestions there.  "https://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi".  Many of the suggestions that are noted are ones you have tried.  But there was also a suggestion of replacing the literal "localhost" with its equivalent IP address, "127.0.0.1".  You might try that.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that many GPU-related stuff won't work without a working display. Sadly, X11 forwarding doesn't work in those cases. At this point, it is not clear if this is your case, or if it is simply that you have the wrong DISPLAY number. You may try:

1. Connecting a physical monitor and keyboard to the board, opening a terminal and running `echo $DISPLAY`. (in the keyboard/monitor session, **not** the SSH session). Then set that on your remote session as `export DISPLAY=:X` (where X is what was printed before).
2. If you are using GStreamer then use nvoverlaysink which doesn't require X. You will need a monitor connected to the board though.

Answer (score 0):

Installing (ARM64 for a recent Jetson, or your other host arch) [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/fr/download/linux/) or [NoMachine](https://downloads.nomachine.com/download/?id=114&distro=ARM) may help for this case. (a reboot may be required).
It might provide the virtual display that you're lacking.

Then you may be able to log in from remote host and use X forwarding using ssh -X (or -Y).